# IOS 4.3.2 MapKit Annotations

Tags: ios, mapkit

Hello we have an app that we are working on that is having some issuse getting the annotations to function correctly.  The app builds and installs fine... there are about 50k pins being loaded from a database on the ipad...

The problem is that every pin will display the same annotation information when pressed... can't figure out how to have it reference the correct database field when a pin is pressed (the pins are all being displayed in the correct locations so we know it is referencing the database)

I imagine it's something here?

```
- (void) loadThePushPinInMap  {
NSString * filename= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"geocoded" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename];
NSString *strippedPartOne = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
NSArray *rows = [strippedPartOne componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
int size = [rows count];
for (int i =0; i < size; i++) {
    if(i==0)
        continue;
    // This is now the data being parse
    NSArray * line = [[rows objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


    double lat =[[[line objectAtIndex:5] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet   whitespaceCharacterSet]] doubleValue];
    double lon =[[[line objectAtIndex:6] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] doubleValue];

    //MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
    //region.center.latitude = lat ;
    //region.center.longitude = lon;
    //region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    //region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = lat;
    coordinate.longitude = lon;          


    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
    annotation.title = [rows objectAtIndex:0];
    annotation.subtitle = [rows objectAtIndex:4];

     //[_mapView addAnnotation:annotation]; 
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

}
```

}

Here is the MKAnnotationsview code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKFoundation.h>

// Post this notification to re-query callout information.
MK_EXTERN NSString * const MKAnnotationCalloutInfoDidChangeNotification;

#if (__IPHONE_4_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED)

enum {
MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone = 0,      // View is at rest, sitting on the map.
MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting,      // View is beginning to drag (e.g. pin lift)
MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging,      // View is dragging ("lift" animations are complete)
MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling,     // View was not dragged and should return to it's    starting position (e.g. pin drop)
MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding         // View was dragged, new coordinate is set and view   should return to resting position (e.g. pin drop)
};

typedef NSUInteger MKAnnotationViewDragState;

#endif // #if (__IPHONE_4_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED)

@class MKAnnotationViewInternal;
@protocol MKAnnotation;

MK_CLASS_AVAILABLE(NA, 3_0)
@interface MKAnnotationView : UIView
{
@private
MKAnnotationViewInternal *_internal;
}

- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString     *)reuseIdentifier;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *reuseIdentifier;

// Classes that override must call super.
- (void)prepareForReuse;

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <MKAnnotation> annotation;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;

// By default, the center of annotation view is placed over the coordinate of the annotation.
// centerOffset is the offset in screen points from the center of the annotion view.
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint centerOffset;

// calloutOffset is the offset in screen points from the top-middle of the annotation view,    where the anchor of the callout should be shown.
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint calloutOffset;

// Defaults to YES. If NO, ignores touch events and subclasses may draw differently.
@property (nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;

// Defaults to NO. This gets set/cleared automatically when touch enters/exits during tracking  and cleared on up.
@property (nonatomic, getter=isHighlighted) BOOL highlighted;

// Defaults to NO. Becomes YES when tapped on in the map view.
@property (nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated;

// If YES, a standard callout bubble will be shown when the annotation is selected.
// The annotation must have a title for the callout to be shown.
@property (nonatomic) BOOL canShowCallout;

// The left accessory view to be used in the standard callout.
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *leftCalloutAccessoryView;

// The right accessory view to be used in the standard callout.
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *rightCalloutAccessoryView;

// If YES and the underlying id<MKAnnotation> responds to setCoordinate:, 
// the user will be able to drag this annotation view around the map.
@property (nonatomic, getter=isDraggable) BOOL draggable NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0);

// Automatically set to MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting, Canceling, and Ending when necessary.
// Implementer is responsible for transitioning to Dragging and None states as appropriate.
@property (nonatomic) MKAnnotationViewDragState dragState NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0);

// Developers targeting iOS 4.2 and after must use setDragState:animated: instead of   setDragState:.
- (void)setDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newDragState animated:(BOOL)animated    NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_2);


@end
```

Here is the Delegate.h codes.....

```
#import "MapinAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MapinAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary    *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
 Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store  enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
 If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of  applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
 */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
 */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Called when the application is about to terminate.
 Save data if appropriate.
 See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
 */
```

}

@end

Here are the Delegate.m codes....

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MapinAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: The problem could be in your `viewForAnnotation:` delegate method, where the actual view is created.

Comment: Do you set the annotation property of your annotation view correctly?
Could you provide your `viewForAnnotation:` code?

Comment: Added the Code for the viewForAnnotation above

Comment: @Monergy I don't think he was asking to see Apple's header file.  Can you show us your implementation of viewForAnnotation: and/or the delegate code?

Comment: Thanks Thompsonian  Just posted the delegate files above... really confused right now!

Comment: perhaps this is nothing but in the first section of code I posted above the call being made at `annotation.subtitle = [rows objectAtIndex:4];`  corresponds to the address being displayed on all of the pins.... am I wrong in assuming that I need to make a different call to the database at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Use CustomAnnotaion which is inherited by MKAnnotation only, in that class assign your own properties, like locationDetails, locationImage, etc.

To add this information, update your MKAnnotatinView, by implementing this delegate 
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

Example:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/805_Consuming_XML_Feed_and_Displaying_Public_Information_on_the_MapView_Control.aspx

Comment: I just tried to add the delegate mentioned above but I'm getting a pop up stating that MKAnnotationView is locked?  I tired to unlock it to make these changes but it's saying that I don't "own" it so I'm not permitted to change it?